# How to implement 'nested' for in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to achieve a 'nested' for loop for my class but unfortunately i cant use `&&` in for
Here's my javascript code:

```
class Card {
    constructor(suit, card, value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.card = card;
        this.value = value;
    }
    showCardInfo() {
        console.log(`Suit: ${this.suit}, Name: ${this.nameCard}, Value: ${this.value}`)
    }

class DeckOfCard {
    constructor() {
        this.deck = [];
        let suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "clubs", "hearts"];
        let cards = ["Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
        let values = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"];
        for (let suit of suits) {
            for (let card of cards) {
                this.deck.push(new Card(suit, card));
            }
        }
    }
}

deck = new DeckOfCard()
console.log(deck.deck)
```

this is my terminal when i console.log()

```
 Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Ace', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Two', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Three', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Four', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Five', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Six', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Seven', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Eight', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Nine', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Ten', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Jack', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'Queen', value: undefined },
  Card { suit: 'hearts', card: 'King', value: undefined },
```

How can I add the value for each card?

Comment: please add `Card`.

Comment: Sorry!! I just edited and added my class Card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you know that each index of the card is going to map properly to the index of its value, then I would recommend switching from a for in to a

```js
for(i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  this.deck.push(new Card(suit, cards[i], values[i]));
}
```

However, you could also change cards from an array of strings to an array of objects, each containing two values, like `let cards = [{card: "Ace", value: "A"}, {card: "Two", value: 2}, ...]`
then using the same for in loop and accessing `card.card` and `card.value`

Answer (score 0):

You need a classic loop for the index to get a items from both same length arrays.

```
for (let index = 0; index < cards.length; index++) {
    this.deck.push(new Card(suit, cards[index], values[index]));
}
```

And an implementation of `value` in `Card`.

```
class Card {
    constructor(suit, card, value) {
        // ...
        this.value = value;
```